# Java ArrayList not allowing me to add from outside constructor

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

```
public class Start {
    public Register theReg = new Register();
    public static Start go = new Start();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Register theReg = new Register();
        go.regUsers();

        if(theReg.logIn("jsmith","password")) {
            System.out.println("You're logged in as " +
                               theReg.userLoggedIn.getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("dang");
        }
    }

    public void regUsers() {
        Student regJoe =
            theReg.regSeniorStaff("Joe smith", "password", "jsmith", 1);
    }
}

public class Register {
    public ArrayList<People> users;
    public People userLoggedIn;

    public Register () {
        users = new ArrayList<People>();
        users.add(new Student("john","password","jo",1));
        userLoggedIn = null;
    }

    public Student regStudent(String name, String password,
            String username, int stuId) {
        Student s = new Student(name, password, username, stuId);
        users.add(s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking I've just missed out something silly. Like....

The start methods will create a new `Register` object, which has its `ArrayList`. Then a bit down the line it starts registering users using the methods like `regStudent`. But, only the constructor on `Register` lets me add objects to the `ArrayList`; calling the methods to do the same thing later on just doesn't add them. It creates the object but can't add them. Also can't remove things, only `.get` works in them.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: no errors, basically if i call the regStudent method from outside of the class (having made a new register object) that method creates the new student object but can't add it to the list.

The users.add(...) part in the constructer works, just never in any of the other methods in the class.

Comment: Show us the code where you're calling regStudent and then checking the result.

Comment: Do you get the Student object back correctly?

Comment: Explain how the method "can't" add the object to the list. Does it tell you in a deep, emotionless voice, "Sorry, I can't let you do that, graeme."???

Comment: How did you *conclude* that it "doesn't work"?

Comment: i've updated the original post with more code.

It may aswell talk to me in a deep emotionless voice, it'd have the same effect.

If i call size or look at the objects in the register class later on it'll only have the 1 object in it that was created in the constructer. This is after calling regStudent multiple times in my start class to add new students. I've also checked, it creates the object but doesn't add it to the list.

Thanks,
Graeme

Comment: It's clear that you don't understand what you're doing. Read through the tutorial I posted and try again. Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: No need to be condescending to someone because they don't know things that you know.

Comment: You don't have a regSeniorStaff method that I can see.  If you mean it to be regStudent then I think it should work.

Comment: I think Stefan saw my post before i added the updated code, which is fair enough as i left a lot to the imagination.

Comment: Also, for this to work, I hope student extends people.  Your OO isn't actually that bad, although GET RID of the public variables users anduserLoggedIn if you plan on turning this homework in!

Comment: @graeme: I can understand people getting snippy at you, because your handling of us is infuriating. You are not providing enough of your code to allow us to debug it, and not enough information to guess our way through. If you don't want to paste lots of code here you can use PasteBin.com . But please either give us a chance or follow rob's advice and learn to do your own debugging!

Comment: Bill, student does extend people, and public variable are my downfall. Will take a look at these, thanks.
  
Carl, i'm sorry, it's my first time here. I didn't want to stick in looads of code for one small problem. Next time i will post the whole thing.

Comment: What we really like to see is the smallest possible amount of code that clearly demonstrates the problem.

Comment: For future questions please read this: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and this: http://sscce.org

Comment: where is this method regSeniorStaff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though you are hiding your `theReg` global var.  You are most likely querying the global and seeing that only the constructor-added item is in your ArrayList.

```
public class Start {
    public Register theReg = new Register(); //<<---- your global var
    public static Start go = new Start();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Register theReg = new Register();  // <<---- hiding the global
        go.regUsers();

        if(theReg.logIn("jsmith","password")) 
          System.out.println("You're logged in as " + theReg.userLoggedIn.getName());
        else 
          System.out.println("dang");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the problem, thanks for pointing it out. Something i didn't know/didn't realise before!

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how to use classes? The naming in this example doesn't make a lot of sense. Why does a "Register" have a "userLoggedIn" "People" object? Wouldn't it make more sense if that was a "Person" object?

```
Register r = new Register().
r.regStudent( ... );
r.regStudent( ... );
```

Should work fine.

My guess is that you have something like this:

```
public static void registerStudent()
{
   Register r = new Register();
   r.add( ... );
}
```

Am I right?

You assume we can read minds, so I gave it a shot. It sounds like you may be repeatedly instantiating your register object, rather than actually holding a single reference and calling methods on it. That would create the behavior you described.

**Edit:** 
It looks like you don't know how to use classes. Here's a tutorial:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: No, actually the way you did it first is how i'm doing it (shown in the updated question, i added more code). The code i've put up isn't the whole 2 classes, the rest of them shouldn't really help in solving the problem i don't think and kind of over complicates things. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I still think you should read some kind of OOP tutorial. Your design makes no sense. If Register holds a list of registered students, can only one person log in at a time? The class names "Register", "Start", and "People" don't correspond to their actual real-life meanings, and your method and variable naming conventions need help.

I was trying to be nice, but your code needs serious work.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger.  Eclipse has a good debugger; you can set a breakpoint on the line `users.add(s)` and inspect the contents of the list `users`.

You might also want to double-check that your regStudent method is being called during execution.  If you're using Eclipse, you can right-click and find all references to that method in your workspace, and make sure one of those is being called during execution.

Comment: Thanks, i had tried running the debugger earlier (i'm using eclipse). I'll have another go.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you have *two* variables names `theReg` - one is an instance member of the `Start` class, the other a local variable in the `main()` method. Then you add a person to one of these `Register` instances and ask the other one whether the person has been added.